# How do I increase the the size of subplots in pair plot?

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

I've a dataset in which there are 15 different numeric columns and I would like to plot a pair plot using seaboard. However the image size of subplots is too small to make any inference from it.

I've tried using height and aspect with pair plot. However it doesn't seems to be working for me. The plot size keeps on reducing. The same goes for fig size.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(40,40))
sns.pairplot(df)
plt.show()
```

I'm expecting a a good enough size of all the pairs so that some inference can be made on the same. However I'm getting plots too small in size to even recognise the column name.

Comment: Note that `sns.seaborn` is not a valid command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command works for me.

I was not aware that in Jupyter notebook we can maximise the output to its actual size.

So essentially, below works just fine.

```py
plt.figure(figsize=(100,100))
sns.pairplot(df)
plt.show()
```